# Getting around the lack of GPT support with CentOS 5.4

Tags: centos, gpt

Last night I upgraded a server (Dell 2970) to have four 1TB Hard Drives in RAID 5 which leaves a 3TB block.  I tried to partition this but keep getting an error that GPT is not supported so.

I found a site online telling me I need to run the dd command and right random data to /dev/sda.  This is great (if it works) but taking forever. I have two more machines to upgrade today and not a chair in sight!  Does anyone have advice on how I can avoid this issue beforehand?

Thank You for your advice and support.

Comment: You should have gotten a proper server. Seriously. One that supports light's out - by having a remote desktop solution integrated. I was upgrading the BIOS on my servers two months ago and installing operating systems - NOT being at the colocation facility. Check what Dell offers in this area and get your servers upgraded.

Comment: You probably mean the DRAC cards. The 2970 should work with DRAC5.

Comment: @TomTom - DRACs are common add-ons to Dell servers. It certainly is a "proper server," it just seems that the OP left that option off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need such a large partition? I would split it up into smaller chunks using LVM on top of the RAID array, to avoid using unsupported workarounds.

Comment: To the guys who mention the DRAC card, I do have a DRAC card but need to be here so I can upgrade three more systems after this machine is done.  But thank you anyhow. 

The RAID array was created in the Dell Utility.  Should I great a software RAID array in the CentOS installer and put LVM on top of that?  I don't have much skills in manually partitioning my drives what I have right now is 

/dev/sda1 is 2 gigs for /boot 
/dev/sda2 VolGroup00 is 700 Gigs 
and than the rest is free space. 

Still getting same error about GPT.

Comment: If you have a PERC5/i or PERC6/i in there, you better leave the array configured there, and build the LVM on top of that (should show up as a really large /dev/sda)

You can create another VG on the free space, or use the free space as a new PV for another LV in VolGroup00 - that's up to you

Comment: Thank you, this is what I did and it worked.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can install CentOS onto GPT disk layouts using a combination of SystemRescueCD, CentOS 5.0 and a patched version of grub.

Although it does involve unsupported work-arounds this is only for the installation itself. The result is a standard CentOS server.

It is quite a lengthy process but can be achieved and I have written up this how to [Install CentOS onto large partitions using gpt disk layout](http://richardjh.org/blog/install-centos-onto-large-partitions-using-gpt-disk-layout/) on my blog.

Comment: Richard, your link is broken, would you try to fix it please? Thanks.

Comment: Chopper3: Sorry about that. I have set up a new blog and edited the link so it should work again.

Comment: I get a lot of people click through to my site from this link but the answer here has only one upvote and my post has no comments.
I want to make sure that my post helps people get around the limitations of CentOS5 installation. If it doesn't, can you let me know so I can add more detail?

Comment: If your drives are 2Tb or less it's much easier to just use SystemRescueCD to convert the GPT partition tables on the drives to MSDOS (if you are stuck using CentOS 5 for compatibility reasons). I did this last night to solve the SolusVM Xen problem.

Comment: If you have <2TB drives, yes you don't need to mess about with GPT and can use MSDOS.